# How does this circuit go into latch-up mode?

Tags: oscillator

The circuit is shown below. What it is supposed to do is to oscillate, and allow for the light bulb to flash periodically.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiiTUP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That is all well and good, but I want to know exactly, how it works. However, while I was messing around with the values of C1 and C2, I had stumbled upon something incredibly interesting, yet annoying.

For when the ratio of C1 to C2 is less than some value(this value depends on the capacitance of C2), the circuit will go into latch-up mode after oscillating for random period of time. Try as I might, I couldn't seem to figure out why. So I ask, how does this circuit go into latch up mode, and why does the ratio of C1 to C2 matter?

My C1 is 0.1uF and C2 is 0.01uF and it oscillates for a random time before it latches up.
For a C2 of 0.01uF, the minimum capacitance I managed to get it to oscillate it at is when C1 is 0.47uF.

I have been doing up a document for this, and I will share it. In case someone wants to know how I think the circuit works. Feel free to edit it...
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Vp0m1JMxUysZ_kG1tjhBMVTL83eYdVbjilB-7E_DXl8/edit

Comment: Please tell us (in your question, not in the comments) which values of C1 and C2 oscillate (and at what frequency) and which values of C1 and C2 latch up, and an rough indication of how long before they do. Also, CircuitLab is finicky. You do not have a ground symbol. Although technically unneeded, you may get strange results when modeling without one.

Comment: Ah. About that. The C1 and C2 values that allow for the circuit to oscillate is 0.47uF and 0.01uF. For latch-up, C1 and C2 is 0.1uF and 0.01uF. As for how long before they latch up, it is not constant and varies a lot. As for the frequency, it is not important.

Comment: frequency wouldn't be important compared to the transistor's R'e which is the main part of this rc time constant. Temperature would be.